# Using polymer in aptana studio 3 on mac

Tags: macos, polymer, aptana3

I am trying to get polymer installed and running my mac. I have downloaded all the files needed but when I use insert a test file I get an error saying that the "polymer field is not recognized". Can someone help please.Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <!-- Load platform.js for polyfill support. -->
    <script src="bower_components/bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
    <!-- import a custom element. -->
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/bower_components/polymer-ui-field/polymer-ui-field.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/bower_components/polymer-ui-icon/polymer-ui-icon.html">
    <!-- add a wee bit of styling. -->
    <style>
         html {
               font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Roboto', 'Arial', sans-serif;
               font-size: 14px;
               }

         polymer-ui-field {
                border: 1px solid #000;
                margin: 10px;
                height: 40px;
               }
     </style>
  </head>


      <body>
            <polymer-ui-field>
            <polymer-ui-icon icon="favorite"></polymer-ui-icon>
             <input placeholder="This is a simple Polymer test using the polymer-ui-field and the polymer-ui-icon." flex>
             </polymer-ui-field>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to contact you regarding another question can u provide a way in the profile settings? I've heard that you have no longer access to a computer and have a solution so you can keep developing. ( people reading this... please don't down vote, I'm tring to help a person when helped will erase this comment, thanks for your mercy in advance )

Answer (score 0):

Your imports and script tag have `bower_components` doubled up.  If this does not accurately reflect your file structure, you should remove the extra `bower_components`. If this does reflect your file structure, you should un-nest the second `bower_components` folder, as this may be interfering with relative file path references in the imported components.